# Using a Delegate Control to add content into the body of the page without javascript

Tags: delegate-control

Is there a way to use a delegate control targeting "AdditionalPageHead" to add a control into the body of the page without resorting to javascript? The solution can't involve javascript as the control being added is a noscript tag.

I've successfully added the control into the page by adding an event listener to the Page's PreRender event. However, changes made to a page (publishing) are not saved when this is done. Is there another way to do this that doesn't invalidate changes made to a page being saved?

**Update**
I've got something that looks to work that I'll keep testing. What (if any) downsides are there to this approach:

- In the delegate control OnInit method, subscribe to page load event:

  this.Page.Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
- In Page_Load event handler, add control to page's controls collection:

  HtmlGenericControl noscript = new HtmlGenericControl("noscript");
          this.Page.Form.Parent.Controls.AddAt(this.Page.Form.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(this.Page.Form) + 1, noscript);

Comment: You're approach sounds correct. What is not working? I'm unsure as to your comment about the publishing page.

Comment: Originally I was adding the control before the Form element, and this was keeping the publishing page it was used on from retaining any changes when a user edits it and saves.

Comment: I'd just like to get others' input on how best to implement this from a performance and functionality perspective.